# Spartacus API calls return 504 (Gateway Timeout) when running using Server Side Rendering (SSR)

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to get Spartacus to work with SSR. When opening the default URL, http://localhost:4200, the storefront renders, as expected, but only after I clear the site data first. When I attempt to browse the storefront, API calls fail with a 504 (Gateway timeout). Chrome dev tools indicates the error is happening in the service worker. At this point, I'm wondering if I configured Spartacus incorrectly. When running Spartacus using *yarn start* rather than *yarn serve:ssr*, I can load the home page and browse the site normally.

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Chrome Version: 73.0.3683.75
Node version: 11.15.0
Angular CLI version: 8.3.8
Yarn version: 1.19.1
```

```
ng new ssr-spartacus-app --style=scss
cd ssr-spartacus-app
ng add @spartacus/schematics --baseUrl https://localhost:9002 --baseSite cmssiteuid --pwa --ssr
rm src/app/app.component.html
echo "<cx-storefront>Loading...</cx-storefront>" > src/app/app.component.html
yarn build:ssr
yarn serve:ssr
```

Before running yarn build:ssr, I made following change to the app.module.ts file:

Before

```
      context: {
        baseSite: ['cmssiteuid'],
      },
```

After

```
      authentication: {
        client_id: 'mobile_android',
        client_secret: 'secret',
      },
      context: {
        urlParameters: ['baseSite', 'language', 'currency'],
        baseSite: ['cmssiteuid'],
      },
```

I also set anonymousConsents to false. With this set to true, I was getting a lot of CORs errors.

If been scratching my head with this for a little while now and I'm hoping someone with more knowledge of Spartacus' inner workings can shed some light on why Spartacus is behaving this way with SSR.

Comment: Hi David, can you provide more info:

.1. Which API calls fail (all of them?) 

2. Is SSR working, i.e. if you disable JavasScript in Chrome console, do you see rendered static view? (you can also check if rendered HTML exist in page source) .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I can give you some certain recipe to fix the issue, obviously I need more details and logs relates to your problem, but still, based on my experience I can share with you some tips and tricks about how we should play with such issues (which relates to SSR).

**Some set of theory which relates to SSR**

- https://angular.io/guide/universal (you can feel free to use Angular official documentation as a primary source, cuz Spartacus uses Angular OOTB features to make it works)
- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/
- https://enable.cx.sap.com/tag/tagid/spartacus (SSR related videos)

**Practical approaches for debugging SSR**

- You should observe and analyze console output during starting your application in Node.js
- You can use SSR configuration from example Storefront application (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/develop/projects/storefrontapp) like a starting point, cuz OOTB SSR works like a charm
- Something from Spartacus team https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/how-to-debug-server-side-rendered-storefront/

**Common set of theory to ensure that application has been configured correctly**

- SAP Commerce Cloud configuration for working with Spartacus https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud/
- Take a look on the guide https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/ to ensure, that your frontend application has correct configuration
- Double check your configuration which B2cStorefrontModule is using (here you can find an example project here https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/develop/projects/storefrontapp)
- Take a look on Network and Console browser tabs and try to resolve all errors

Answer (score 0):

did you turn off PWA?

Turn PWA off.

As soon as Spartacus is installed in PWA mode, a service worker is installed, and it serves a cached version of index.html, along with the js files. This results in SSR being completely skipped. The following steps describe how to turn off PWA:

Check that there are no service workers registered in your app. If you do find any service workers, remove them.

Turn PWA off in your app module configuration, as follows:

```
 StorefrontModule.withConfig({
       backend: {
         occ: {
           baseUrl: 'https://[your_enpdoint],
         },
       },
       pwa: {
         enabled: false,
       },
 };
```

Rebuild your local Spartacus libraries by running the following command:

```
yarn build:core:lib
```

Build your local Spartacus shell app by running the following command:

```
 yarn build --prod
```

Build the SSR version of your shell app by running the following command:

```
yarn build:ssr
```

Start Spartacus with the SSR server by running the following command:

```
 yarn serve:ssr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 504 after hitting the API service you need to check your API logs.

**IF you have err log:**

```
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1644915623,"nanoOfSecond":929833000},"thread":"hybrisHTTP1","level":"ERROR","loggerName":"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet","message":"Context initialization failed","thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"Error creating bean with name 'cartEntriesController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStockValidator' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/v2/validators-v2-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.stock.impl.DefaultCommerceStockFacade] to required type [de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.stock.CommerceStockFacade]: Failed to convert value of type 'de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.stock.impl.DefaultCommerceStockFacade' to required type 'de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.stock.CommerceStockFacade'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'de.hybris.platform.ycommercewebservices.stock.impl.DefaultCommerceStockFacade' to required type 'de.hybris.platform.commercewebservices.core.stock.CommerceStockFacade': no matching editors or conversion strategy found","message":"Error creating bean with name 'cartEntriesController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStockValidator'
```

**You can try resolution:**
Remove template extension ycommercewebservices extension from manifest.json, rebuild and redeploy with "Migrate Data" mode.